# Is there a way to produce a diagram like this in mermaid?

Tags: diagram, mermaid

Is there a way to make a diagram like below in Mermaid?

[image: diagram]

I have bumped into 2 problems in an attempt to do so in mermaid.

1. How to make a node where two sub-nodes are attached together side by side?
2. If using subgraph for each node of a sub-node pair, how to maintain direction(orientation) separately between global scope and subgraph scope? It seems like Mermaid ignores the subgraph scope direction(orientation) and applies the global scope direction when a node inside a subgraph is linked to a node inside another subgraph. The following code generates the below. You see that even though the subgraphs' direction is set to be LR, TB from global scope direction is applied.

```
flowchart TB
    subgraph node0
        direction LR
            node00[data constructor]
            node01[pointer]
            node00 --adjacent--- node01
            
    end
    
    node01 ---> node10
    
    subgraph node1
        direction LR
            node10[data]
            node11[pointer]
            node10 --adjacent--- node11
    end
```

[image: diagram made using Mermaid]

Comment: I have a similar issue, I don't think mermaid is capable of this. I have resorted to HTML tables and hard-coding my own svgs.

Comment: @GraemeStuart If you don't know this, there is what is called graphviz that can do this but mermaid is easier to use on the go. It is a shame mermaid isn't capable of this. :)

Comment: Maybe I'd need to also learn how to hard-code svg for the maximum manipulation.

Comment: Yes, I'm integrating with markdown in a jekyll site so I want to be able to add simple diagrams. If it's simple then svg works well.

Comment: @GraemeStuart Aha, you're smart.  I might try the same strategy in the future. :)

Comment: Mermaid documentation shows that direction in subgraphs is possible. Would love to see it function as defined.

Comment: Turns out that it is possible. Just don't reach inside a subgraph. In other words, reference the subgraph from outside; don't reference the items inside from the outside. In your code, just change `node01 ---> node10` to `node0 ---> node1` and direction functions properly.